# Laravel : Load a view after posting

Tags: php, post, view, laravel

In Codeigniter I used to call the view function after posting data. Like below;

Ex: I have a show_products() function which will display list of products. When a user add a new product I'm posting data into add_product() function. If the process is successful I will **not** redirect to the products page, instead load the display function inside the add_product() like this:

```
//Inside the add_product() function
if(success){

   $this->show_products();

}
```

I think, there is no point of reloading the page again. Since we are already in the post function we can straight away set the view after the database insert.

However in laravel I see people redirecting after posting data.

ex:

```
//Inside the postProduct() function
if(success){

   return Redirect::to('products');

}
```

I tried;

```
//Inside the postProduct() function
if(success){

   $this->getIndex();// this is my product display function

}
```

but it didn't work.

Do we have a benefit by loading the view in the post function without redirecting every time?

If so how can I achieve the same thing with the laravel?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not about the `Laravel`, instead, it's about a good or right way of doing things. In other words, it's a good programming practice to redirect to another route/page after you successfully submit a form.

Even in `CodeIgniter` or plain `Php` I do like this approach and encourage other developers to do that. So, the question is why this redirect is better than directly calling another method from the same request to show another view/page ?

This is the life cycle of the process:

1. You post a form to a route/action page.
2. You validate the submitted data and upon successful validation you insert the submitted data in to your database, otherwise you redirect back to that form with errors and old user inputs.

So. assume that, you have submitted a form and done saving the data into database successfully. After you save it you done something like this:

```
return View::make('...')->with('success', 'Data saved!');
```

In this case, your user can see the `success` message on the screen but what if the user, presses the <kbd>f5</kbd> key from the keyboard to `refresh` the page (probably, accidentally), the form will be submitted to the same action again and the whole process will be repeated again.

So, if you had a redirect after form submission then, `refreshing` the page won't make any request to that form again.

Google search result on [form resubmit on refresh.](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=form%20resubmit%20on%20refresh&rlz=1C1KMZB_enBD539BD539&oq=form%20resubmit&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5797j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8), check the links, may be first one/two, you'll get better idea about the problem and the benefits of redirection after form submission.

Answer (score 1):

in Codeigniter to redirect page we have `redirect()` function.

```
if(success){
    redirect('products');
}
```

Comment: Hi Moorthy GK, Thanks but I don't want to redirect. I want to load the view inside the POST function. If you redirect, I think you are doing one more extra step.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to return `Redirect`. The reason people use it quite often in larvel is because it's comfy.

You can return something else, eg. a view:

```
return View::make('home.index')->with('var',$var);
```

Comment: Thanks Tom!, instead of making the View, can I reuse a function I already have. Something like $this->getIndex(); ?

Comment: In Laravel 3 it works, in L4 I think it should also work, but IMO it's a bad approach. If you do it in that way, you must always check to pass further all needed vars. Using `Return::redirect()` guarantees no problems and you can keep your code DRY. Also - redirect only redirects a route internally in laravel between controllers, so after calling it, all in all there's only one html response generated.

Comment: Forgot about one thing - you can also redirect to controller (not only to a route)

Comment: I have a problem with post request too. Can you please help. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113117/post-request-not-working-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, to redirect after doing a POST, you could return a redirect with a named route:

```
return redirect()->route('my-route-name');
```

Or if you are within the controller that has the route method you want (eg. the `index` method, you could do this as well:

```
return self::index();
```